# Very easy to use 2d (optionally 3d) drawing library / wrapper for directx or opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11, graphics, directx

I'm studying physics and I know C++ at a basic level. at my study it's sometimes really useful to create a program which can graphicly represent some data or do calculations and then graphicly represent them. I read that, for example, to be able to master the basics of openGL I would need to do a 10 week long course of openGL. But that is too much time.

I'm wondering if there are any libraries available (for windows) which allow me to do some easy stuff like:

-DrawPixel(x,y,color)
-DrawCircle/Line/Shape/Polygon([list of points])/Triangle/Square (+rotation)
-DrawImage(filename,width,height,etc...)
-DrawText()

Is there any library which has this easyness? It would be really cool because if I do something (create a program) and I need to explain my team (who have never programmed) how I have done it (the program / results), this would make it much easier to explain!

I looked at SDL, HGE, OpenFrameworks (somewhat the "closest" yet still far away) and a few other popular libraries but they are all so far away.. why is there no such easy library?

Are there any available which are just not being found with the keywords i search in google?

Comment: If you only know the basics of C++ then don't use DirectX or OpenGL at all, those are some huge and advanced libraries. Before you even try using them I would advice you learn more about C++.

Comment: well I can effectively write path searching algorithms and display the output in a console, but graphics is another story/side of C++!

Comment: As an OpenGL programmer I can agree with you, it's a completely other side of programming, and its a really advanced side of programming.

Comment: A few years back I was working on a small library to do 'simple' things just like this, for people just like you. Maybe it needs a reboot. There really arn't any dead simple solutions that I know of, but would love to see if anyone else can provide any.

Comment: Put on hold.. where should I migrate the question then?

Comment: Give gtk with goocanvas a chance ;) It works for linux/windows and others. And it is very simple to use. It is a clasical "canvas" implementation with active objects on the canvas and so on... BTW: Can't understand closing this question!

Comment: Yeah me too.. I see many questions like this which are not closed and I missed the "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic" in the FAQ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you take a look at [cinder](http://libcinder.org/). Try out the [Hello Cinder](http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.5/hello_cinder.html) tutorial. I think you will find it supports your needs by providing an abstraction layer above DirectX or OpenGL.

Comment: well if there is nothing simpeler (and this is kinda simple! :o) then I will go with this ;)